# How do you perform fuzzy string matching in r

Tags: r, string, matching

I have two dataframes with multiple columns. I have provided below a shorter version of the data frames which contains the relevant columns for the question.

STR(DF1)

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ itemid      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ userid      : int  650 635 1 514 250 210 5 72 77 252
 $ rating      : int  3 4 5 5 4 5 4 4 5 5
 $ time        : Date, format: "1998-03-31" "1997-11-07" "1997-09-22" ...
 $ title       : chr  "Toy Story " "Toy Story " "Toy Story " "Toy Story " ...
 $ release_date: chr  "1995" "1995" "1995" "1995" ...
```

DF1

```
 itemid userid rating       time      title release_date
1       1    650      3 1998-03-31 Toy Story          1995
2       1    635      4 1997-11-07 Toy Story          1995
3       1      1      5 1997-09-22 Toy Story          1995
4       1    514      5 1997-09-26 Toy Story          1995
5       1    250      4 1997-12-27 Toy Story          1995
6       1    210      5 1998-02-17 Toy Story          1995
7       1      5      4 1997-09-30 Toy Story          1995
8       1     72      4 1997-11-20 Toy Story          1995
9       1     77      5 1998-01-13 Toy Story          1995
10      1    252      5 1998-04-01 Toy Story          1995
```

STR(DF2)

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ itemid      : int  2844 4936 4936 4972 5078 6684 6689 7264 7264 7880
 $ userid      : int  4477 8871 11628 16885 11628 4222 4222 2092 5943 11628
 $ rating      : int  6 8 5 8 4 6 6 8 6 7
 $ time        : Date, format: "2013-03-09" "2013-05-05" "2013-07-06" ...
 $ title       : chr  "FantÃ´mas - Ã€ l'ombre de la guillotine " "The Bank " "The Bank " "The Birth of a Nation " ...
 $ release_date: chr  "1913" "1915" "1915" "1915" ...
```

DF2

```
 itemid userid rating       time                                    title release_date
1    2844   4477      6 2013-03-09 FantÃ´mas - Ã€ l'ombre de la guillotine          1913
2    4936   8871      8 2013-05-05                                The Bank          1915
3    4936  11628      5 2013-07-06                                The Bank          1915
4    4972  16885      8 2013-08-19                   The Birth of a Nation          1915
5    5078  11628      4 2013-08-23                               The Cheat          1915
6    6684   4222      6 2013-08-24                             The Fireman          1916
7    6689   4222      6 2013-08-24                         The Floorwalker          1916
8    7264   2092      8 2013-03-17                                The Rink          1916
9    7264   5943      6 2013-05-12                                The Rink          1916
10   7880  11628      7 2013-07-19                             Easy Street          1917
```

I want to match the titles across the data sets using fuzzy string matching with Levenshtein distance measure and also like to confirm that the titles are the same the 'release_date' is matched. Is there a better way of performing this task without using a loop? I tried using a for loop with 'agrep' and I ran out of memory. The output should be a data frame but only for the movies that matched.

The original data frames have more than 100K rows.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your  code? there are a few other packages which use levenshtein distance in r, did you try those?

Comment: I have  looked at compare.linkage but the I am unable to understand the output produced and I tried 'agrep' but with one string value only. compare.linkage looks like a better option as per my understanding as it compares two datasets and with multiple columns. I am totally unaware of how to interpret the output. I am performing this operation for the very first time so need some help and guidance from the experts like yourself to learn and be able to do it on my own in the future. I have also tried using compare.linkage and this error came up 'Error: cannot allocate vector of size 43.7 Gb'

Comment: Have a look at `help(agrep)`

Comment: "pattern - a non-empty character string or a character string containing a regular expression (for fixed = FALSE) to be matched. Coerced by as.character to a string if possible". This as per my understanding I need to use a for-loop and this will match only one title at a time in the other data set. I would like to avoid having loops given the size of the datasets

Answer (score 1):

Try `agrep` function

```
title <- c("The Bank", "The Cheat", "The Rink", "The Ring", "Toy Story", "Toy Story 2")
for(i in seq_along(title)){
    x <- agrep(title[i], title[-i], value = TRUE)   
    cat("Title :", title[i], " matched to ", x, "\n")
}
Title : The Bank  matched to   
Title : The Cheat  matched to   
Title : The Rink  matched to  The Ring 
Title : The Ring  matched to  The Rink 
Title : Toy Story  matched to  Toy Story 2 
Title : Toy Story 2  matched to  Toy Story
```